# Send object from pug template to javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I have a node.js + pug application stack. I can send a delete request, but have problem with put/post request with body.
My pug table looks like this

```html
    table.table.table-striped.text-center
        each order in orders
            tr
                td #{order.id}
                td #{moment(order.date).format('DD.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss')}
                td #{order.total_price} €
                td
                    button.btn.btn-success(onClick="archiveOrder(" + order + ")")
                        i.fa.fa-archive
                td
                    button.btn.btn-danger(onClick="deleteOrder(" + order.id + ")")
                        i.fa.fa-trash-o
        else
            tr
                td(colspan=7) There are no items
```

I included a script file in pug that has this content:

```js
function deleteOrder(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: "/orders/" + id,
        success: function () {
            location.reload()
        }
    });
}

function archiveOrder(order) {
    order.archived = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "/orders/" + order.id,
        data: JSON.stringify(order),
        success: function () {
            location.reload()
        }
    });
}
```

Renders ok, delete works fine. How can I send the order I want to archive in the javascript function? I tried `onClick="archiveOrder(" + order + ")"` and `onClick="archiveOrder(#{order})"`
The first one generates

```html
<button class="btn btn-success" onClick="archiveOrder([object Object])" title="Archive order = hide from list">
  <i class="fa fa-archive"></i>
</button>
```

Logicaly it fails with `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` because of `[object Object]` string i think.

The second attempt result in `orders:23 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

How could I send the object `order` from pug's loop into the rest endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML can't render the object. So you can turn the object into a sting with [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
button.btn.btn-success(onClick="archiveOrder(" + JSON.stringify(order) + ")")
```

You will see a JSON string in your markup. The opposite is [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse it back into an object.